# How can I create a wireless hotspot?

Tags: release-freya, wifi

My laptop dual boots Windows 10 and elementary freya. Using connectify and even cmd, I can create a WiFi hotspot in Windows. However, access point mode is not supported in freya. I tried almost every method available here without any success.

My wifi card details are (from `lspci -nn`)

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: 
Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

Is there any way to create the hotspot in order to share internet with my Android phone?

Answer (score 2):

**Wireless Drivers**

Whichever method you choose to create your hotspot, your wireless card will need to support either *Ad-Hoc* or *AP* mode. Examine the output of `iw list` and look for the *Supported interface modes:* section. If *Ad-Hoc* or *AP* are not listed you may have to try installing another driver as there are several for Broadcom devices. You can view the name and version of the current driver in use with the `lshw -c network` command.

**Enable Hotspot (Ad-Hoc)**

Select *Network* from *System Settings*. Select *Wireless* from the left hand panel. A *Use as Hotspot...* button will appear at the bottom of the dialog. Select it and you should now have a Wi-Fi hotspot utilising Ad-Hoc mode with your computers hostname as the SSID.

Note: By default this method will only use WEP encryption. You can modify this behavior by editing the network profile by hand.

Enter 
`sudo scratch-text-editor /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot` in a terminal. Replace (or comment out each line with a #) the *[802-11-wireless-security]* section with the following.

```
[802-11-wireless-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
auth-alg=open
psk=<your desired WPA keye>
```

**Enable Hotspot (AP)**

There is an alternative method detailed [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/3-ways-create-wifi-hotspot-ubuntu/) allowing you to set up a Hotspot utilising the AP mode of your wireless device. One downside to using this method is that you may stop seeing other networks, presumably because it doesn't 'scan' once set in AP mode.

Comment: I can do this without changing `infrastructure` to `ap`. Are you sure that is necessary?

Comment: It could depend on your driver/card? After choosing the hidden network my laptop (Centrino Wireless-N 2230 / driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.16.0-45-generic) refuses to 'connect' in network-indicator then simply cycles to the next available, unless I change that line. YMMV.

Comment: @elmato My driver doesn't support AP mode. I couldn't find any other driver that does. I tried all three methods given at the [link](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/3-ways-create-wifi-hotspot-ubuntu/) page you mentioned.
Also when I tried above mentioned method, I got stuck at step 10.Output of command 10 is given in next comment.

Comment: @elmato (1/2)
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 12:41:44.301110] Application.vala:155: Scratch version: 2.2.0
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 12:41:44.301161] Application.vala:157: Kernel version: 3.16.0-45-generic
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 12:41:44.302075] Settings.vala:158: Loading settings from schema 'org.pantheon.scratch.saved-state'
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 12:41:44.302436] Settings.vala:158: Loading settings from schema 'org.pantheon.scratch.settings'

Comment: @elmato (2/2)
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 12:41:44.302821] [dconf] failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 12:41:44.302890] [dconf] failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 12:41:44.303056] Settings.vala:158: Loading settings from schema 'org.pantheon.scratch.services'
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 12:41:44.305189] [Gtk] cannot open display:

Comment: Try `sudo` instead of `pkexec` (I changed the line to show this)

Comment: What driver *are* you using?

Comment: I feel silly. I didn't see the built in method utilising AdHoc networking until just now. Edited the answer to account for this. Recommend you try that instead...

Comment: @elmato I guess I haven't my problem correctly. My card does support AP mode because in windows I can create hotspot. However in freya  my present driver which is (wl0) doesn't support AP mode. As I want to share my Internet with Android phone adhoc network isn't an option. Is there any driver for my card which supports AP mode or is there any workaround so that I can share Internet without AP mode with my phone.

Comment: @AshokVishnoi Unfortunately as far as I can see, the opensource B43  driver doesn't support your card. You could try updating the wl driver if you haven't already? If you are still determined several other options you could research are 1) Rooting your phone and enabling adhoc networking 2) Root your phone, have it act as the AP with your pc as the client then set up routing manually so the pc is the gateway 3) Use a USB cable and setup 'reverse tethering' 4) Find a win XP driver for your card and experiment with NDISwrapper (unsure if possible with 64bit linux). Sorry I cannot be of help.